# Passing many items in SQLAlchemy session.add

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a schema Alphabets with 26 columns A,B,C....,Z. Now, I would like to add some items(say a list with values a,b,....z) in my database . We can certainly do this in this way by manually typing every column

```
data=Alphabets(A='a', B='b'........ , Z='z')
session.add(data)
session.commit()
```

There definitely must be some way to iterate over the list. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your values in a dictionary and *unpack* it into keyword arguments:

```
values = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', ... 'Z': 'z'}
data = Alphabets(**values)
```